# Has anyone used Dijkstra's algorithm in OPL?

Tags: dijkstra, opl, mining

I have a model for a mining problem. I am working on adding into the model to use the shortest path inside a mine(open pit) for hauling ore and waste. For this, I was thinking of Dijkstra's algorithm. I could not find any example of the use of Dijkstra's algorithm in OPL. Has anyone done it before and can you share some ideas, please.

Answer (score 2):

if you need to write Dijsktra's algorithm then Daniel is right and you d rather use the scripting part. Now if you need a shortest path within an existing OPL model you could use the following shortest path example:

.mod

```
tuple edge
{
   key int o;
   key int d;
   int weight;
}

{edge} edges=...;

{int} nodes={i.o | i in edges} union {i.d | i in edges};
int st=1; // start
int en=8; // end

dvar int obj; // distance
dvar boolean x[edges]; // do we use that edge ?

minimize obj;

subject to
{
obj==sum(e in edges) x[e]*e.weight;

forall(i in nodes) 
    sum(e in edges:e.o==i) x[e]
    -sum(e in edges:e.d==i) x[e]    
    ==
    ((i==st)?1:((i==en)?(-1):0));
}

{edge} shortestPath={e | e in edges : x[e]==1};

execute
{
writeln(shortestPath);
}
```

.dat

```
edges=
{
<1,2,9>,
<1,3,9>,
<1,4,8>,
<1,10,18>,
<2,3,3>,
<2,6,6>,
<3,4,9>,
<3,5,2>,
<3,6,2>,
<4,5,8>,
<4,7,7>,
<4,9,9>,
<4,10,10>,
<5,6,2>,
<5,7,9>,
<6,7,9>,
<7,8,4>,
<7,9,5>,
<8,9,1>,
<8,10,4>,
<9,10,3>,
};
```

which gives

```
// solution (optimal) with objective 19
 {<1 4 8> <4 7 7> <7 8 4>}
```

Comment: Thank you Alex for the example, I will try it. I need to use it as a part of another optimization problem and hence using OPL.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem that can be solved using Dijkstra's algorithm then it seems a bit of overkill to use OPL or CPLEX to solve it. You could code up the algorithm in any programming language and use it from there. I guess that is why you don't find any examples.

If you still want to implement in OPL then use a scripting (`execute`) or a `main` block. The scripting code you can provide there is a superset of JavaScript, so you can implement Dijkstra's algorithm in JavaScript and put it there.